# 7.88 glrenderer is null on MediaQueryList.onPixelRatioChanged

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Since version 7.88 I have this error with the forge-viewer:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'glrenderer')","TypeError: Cannot read property 'glrenderer' of null`

in this location:

`MediaQueryList.onPixelRatioChanged`

my Stacktrace:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'glrenderer')
    at MediaQueryList.onPixelRatioChanged (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.88.0/viewer3D.min.js:18:363918)
    at R.invokeTask (https://<sub-domain>.<domain>.ch/polyfills.b7a09e8149b912e2.js:1:37636)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (https://<sub-domain>.<domain>.ch/main.44847181a35edb80.js:1:1896856)
    at R.invokeTask (https://<sub-domain>.<domain>.ch/polyfills.b7a09e8149b912e2.js:1:37557)
    at fe.runTask (https://<sub-domain>.<domain>.ch/polyfills.b7a09e8149b912e2.js:1:32977)
    at _.invokeTask [as invoke] (https://<sub-domain>.<domain>.ch/polyfills.b7a09e8149b912e2.js:1:38695)
    at M (https://<sub-domain>.<domain>.ch/polyfills.b7a09e8149b912e2.js:1:51451)
    at G (https://<sub-domain>.<domain>.ch/polyfills.b7a09e8149b912e2.js:1:51759)
    at MediaQueryList.he (https://<sub-domain>.<domain>.ch/polyfills.b7a09e8149b912e2.js:1:52042)
```

I'm not aware of how I can fix it.

Comment: we need to understand the context of this error.
Please share a non-confidential reproducible sample through aps[dot]help[at]autodesk[dot]com
Also feel free schedule a chat through [calendly](https://calendly.com/autodesk-platform-services)